# Check failed: vm. Must be able to initialize the VM

Tags: flutter

Flutter app is crashing on release mode only .

> e service connection to gms implementation 2020-06-27 17:33:50.943
> 11703-11703/io.appplus.sharechapplus V/FA: Registered activity
> lifecycle callback 2020-06-27 17:33:50.947
> 11703-11703/io.appplus.sharechapplus I/FirebaseInitProvider:
> FirebaseApp initialization successful 2020-06-27 17:33:50.976
> 11703-11723/io.appplus.sharechapplus E/MemoryLeakMonitorManager:
> MemoryLeakMonitor.jar is not exist! 2020-06-27 17:33:50.978
> 11703-11703/io.appplus.sharechapplus E/Minikin: Could not get cmap
> table size! 2020-06-27 17:33:50.982
> 11703-11703/io.appplus.sharechapplus V/ActivityThread: Skipping new
> config:{1.0 405mcc862mnc [en_US] ldltr sw360dp w360dp h693dp 320dpi
> nrml long port finger -keyb/v/h -nav/h appBounds=Rect(0, 0 - 720,
> 1440) nonFullScreen=0 suim:1 s.133}, config:{1.0 405mcc862mnc [en_US]
> ldltr sw360dp w360dp h693dp 320dpi nrml long port finger -keyb/v/h
> -nav/h appBounds=Rect(0, 0 - 720, 1440) nonFullScreen=0 suim:1 s.133} for app:io.appplus.sharechapplus 2020-06-27 17:33:51.002
> 11703-11703/io.appplus.sharechapplus V/HwPolicyFactory: : success to
> get AllImpl object and return.... 2020-06-27 17:33:51.014
> 11703-11703/io.appplus.sharechapplus V/HwWidgetFactory: : successes to
> get AllImpl object and return.... 2020-06-27 17:33:51.020
> 11703-11703/io.appplus.sharechapplus V/ActivityThread:
> callActivityOnCreate 2020-06-27 17:33:51.025
> 11703-11703/io.appplus.sharechapplus V/FA: onActivityCreated
> 2020-06-27 17:33:51.071 11703-11703/io.appplus.sharechapplus
> E/flutter: [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_data.cc(18)] VM snapshot
> invalid and could not be inferred from settings. 2020-06-27
> 17:33:51.072 11703-11703/io.appplus.sharechapplus E/flutter:
> [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm.cc(248)] Could not setup VM data to
> bootstrap the VM from. 2020-06-27 17:33:51.072
> 11703-11703/io.appplus.sharechapplus E/flutter:
> [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_lifecycle.cc(84)] Could not create Dart
> VM instance. 2020-06-27 17:33:51.072
> 11703-11703/io.appplus.sharechapplus A/flutter:
> [FATAL:flutter/shell/common/shell.cc(268)] Check failed: vm. Must be
> able to initialize the VM. 2020-06-27 17:33:51.072
> 11703-11703/io.appplus.sharechapplus A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT),
> code -6 in tid 11703 (s.sharechapplus), pid 11703 (s.sharechapplus)
> 2020-06-27 17:33:51.085 11703-11746/io.appplus.sharechapplus V/FA:
> Collection enabled 2020-06-27 17:33:51.086
> 11703-11746/io.appplus.sharechapplus V/FA: App package, google app id:
> io.appplus.sharechapplus,
> 1:924335965951:android:872d03adb90ca78532eeca 2020-06-27 17:33:51.092
> 11703-11746/io.appplus.sharechapplus I/FA: App measurement is starting
> up, version: 16250 2020-06-27 17:33:51.092
> 11703-11746/io.appplus.sharechapplus I/FA: To enable debug logging
> run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE 2020-06-27 17:33:51.092
> 11703-11746/io.appplus.sharechapplus I/FA: To enable faster debug mode
> event logging run:
> adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app io.appplus.sharechapplus 2020-06-27 17:33:51.093
> 11703-11746/io.appplus.sharechapplus D/FA: Debug-level message logging
> enabled 2020-06-27 17:33:51.094 11703-11746/io.appplus.sharechapplus
> V/FA: Persisting first open: 1593259430937

```
Flutter (Channel stable, v1.17.4, on Linux, locale en_US.UTF-8)
    • Flutter version 1.17.4 at /home/midhilajm/flutter
    • Framework revision 1ad9baa8b9 (10 days ago), 2020-06-17 14:41:16 -0700
    • Engine revision ee76268252
    • Dart version 2.8.4
```